# Tables from selected database and fields from selected table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a task which I can't solve, and I hope to get some help from you. I want to display all databases from my localhost in a select option, when I select some of these databases I what to show all tables in the selected database in another select option, and when I select some of that tables , I want to dynamically display the selected tables fields (columns). I think it would be better to do that with `jquery`.

To display all databases and tables  and fields I have used `mysql_database_list`, `mysql_table_list`, but I can not do that dynamically. Please help if any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select style='width:150px' id='tbl'>

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#db").change(function() { 
             var selectedDB = $('#db option:selected').val();
             $.ajax( {
                 url :'getTables.php',
                 type:'POST'
                 , data:{db:selectedDB}
                 , success: function(res) {
                     $("#tbl").html(res);
                 }
             });
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use jQuery, it is a good idea to simplify your work. Populate the first select with your database table names. Then bind to the select event on that dropdown and execute a function that will populate the second select with your field names.

For the event binding on select, see : http://api.jquery.com/select/
For the ajax call to populate your second list, see : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/